# Is it possible to install 2 OS onto the SAME virtual machine in Hyper-V, and if yes how to?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, virtual-machine, multi-boot, virtualization

Suppose I already created an virtual machine in hyper-V client with Windows 8.1 install.

Now I also want to install another OS (Ubuntu) onto the **same** VM in hyper-V alongside the already Windows OS install onto it (like Dualboot in the same virtual machine). 
When I start the VM in hyper-V manager, I want to have the option of booting in either Windows or Ubuntu. How to do it step by step?

**Note:** I'm only looking if that can be done in Hyper-V not with other hypervisors (like VirtualBox which base on what I learn in researching link below the subject may somewhat be done).

Link for dualboot inside a virtual machine- https://hardforum.com/threads/can-you-dual-boot-inside-a-virtual-machine.1411006/

Answer (score 2):

On your first Virtual Machine, install the OS of your choice. If it is already installed, partition your drive so that it has enough free space to install another OS.

Then, in Hyper-V you can insert disk or select an ISO to load before it gets to your OS. Set the DVD drive to boot up first and wait for the ISO to boot up amd install your secondary OS. When installing the second OS, install on the partition that does not have your other OS.

Depending on what order you install, you may be stuck with the bootloader from the last OS you installed. This can be fixed later.

If you want, you can set this up in Virtual Box using a .vhd format disk and load it into Hyper-V with everything already set up.